# Which sounds more natural in latin?

Tags: syntax, contemporary-latin, word-order

I know you can often shuffle the order of words in Latin sentences, preserving the meaning of the sentence if you do it right. Still, there are some things that just don't sound "natural" or "adequate" in text.

I often read the Carthusian motto in some different orders.

> Stat crux dum volvitur orbis.

> Dum crux stat, orbis volvitur.

> Stat crux, dum orbis volvitur.

I wonder: is there a more "natural" order for this sentence? If so which order sounds more natural in Latin? Why (not)?

Comment: Those orders aren't all equivalent in meaning -- the first and third mean "The cross stands while the world turns", the second means "While the cross stands, the world turns".